# Generate DLL from Jar using Weblogic java2com?

Tags: java, weblogic

Is it possible to generate a standalone [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) server packaged in a DLL from a java jar file using `java2com` from [Oracle WebLogic Server](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/wls/WJCOM/tools.htm#WJCOM163)?

Comment: what do you want and why ?

Comment: @Ravi I want what I wrote in the question. What is not clear? I want to make a [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) server in a DLL and use it from VBA in Excel.